# How to search for given word or character in ArrayList and show those who match and sort them

Tags: java, string, oop, comparator, comparable

I'm still new to java. My task was to find all Producers in ArrayList who matches the word or character that the user inserts and return a list of those words sorted by their field.

For example, we have Producers {"Alex","Bob","Amanda","Jack", "Jari"}

User wants to seach for "A"program returns sorted==>"Alex","Amanda" User wants to seach for "Ja"program returns sorted==>"Jack", "Jari" User wants to seach for "Bob"program returns sorted==>"Bob"

this is all code I have for now in my main method:

```
Producers producer1 = new Producers("Alex");
Producers producer2 = new Producers("Jack");
Producers producer3 = new Producers("Jari");
```

Adding all producers into ArrayList

```
Producers.allProducers.add(producer1);
Producers.allProducers.add(producer2);
Producers.allProducers.add(producer3);`
```

Then we have another Object called Clothing where we had a task to add our producer for each piece of clothing

```
Clothing wClothing1 = new Clothing("Sneakers", 6.99, ProductsType.SHOES); // name,price,ProductsType as ENUMClothing 
Clothing wClothing2 = new Clothing("AShoe", 1.99, ProductsType.SHOES);
Clothing wClothing3 = new Clothing("Cocktail dress", 15.99, ProductsType.DRESSES);
wClothing1.setProducers(producer1);
wClothing2.setProducers(producer2);
wClothing3.setProducers(producer3);
```

Adding all clothing into ArrayList

```
Items.clothingItemList.add(wClothing1);
Items.clothingItemList.add(wClothing2);
Items.clothingItemList.add(wClothing3);`
```

We need to search, find and sort words only by producers in Items.clothingItemList. So I created a sorting method that can only sort all producers but can't search for them and then sort.

```
public static void getItemByProducer() {
 Collections.sort(Items.clothingItemList, new SortByProducersComparator());
    System.out.println(Items.clothingItemList.toString());
}
```

I created also a new class called SortByProducersComparator():

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SortByProducersComparator implements Comparator<Items> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Items o1, Items o2) {
        int c =0;
        c=o1.getProducersName().compareTo(o2.getProducersName());
        return c;
}}
```

We need to do this task using: Comparator, Comparable.
we cant use it to stream.

Please help, I hope my explanation of the task was good enough

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please keep formatting to a useful minimum. In particular, please don't start sentences with `>` unless you specifically want to quote a passage from somewhere else.

Comment: Hello, i hope it looks better, im still new to this

Comment: Hello Sarah not sure if that would help but could you create method that take clothingItemList as paramter and another string (which is the user input ) then it return array list that match that find maybe using while or for loop it could even call getItemByProducer() at the end to do the sorting also but you would need to modify this getItemByProducer()  to accept an arraylist